# Builder pattern. Expansion interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I have builder:

```
public abstract class ScriptBuilder {
    public void buildScript() {
        this.commandList = Lists.newArrayList();
    }
    public abstract void buildSleepCommand(long time);
    public abstract void buildSynchronizationCommand();
    public abstract void buildTouchDownCommand(TouchPoint touchPoint);
    public abstract void buildTouchUpCommand();
    public List<String> getScript() {
        return commandList;
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class StandardScriptBuilder extends ScriptBuilder{
…
}
```

I need to construct a new builder, which implements the new interface. This new interface is based on the interface ScriptBuilder:

```
class NewScriptBuilder extends StandardScriptBuilder{
    public void buildNewCommand(TouchPoint startTouchPoint, TouchPoint endTouchPoint) {
        buildTouchDownCommand(startTouchPoint);
        buildSynchronizationCommand();
        buildTouchDownCommand(endTouchPoint);
    }
    …
}
```

Is there any pattern that will extend the existing builder interface and keep builder advantage? I mean, if we extend the interface, we can not do:

```
ScriptBuilder builder = new NewScriptBuilder();
…
builder.buildNewCommand;
```

If there is no solution, it is normal to use?:

```
((NewScriptBuilder)builder).buildNewCommand;
```

Thx.

---

I mean: For example, we can use Decorator pattern:

```
public abstract class Decorator extends ScriptBuilder {...} ...

public class OahDecorator extends Decorator {
...
    public void buildNewCommand() {
    ...
    }
}
```

it is a normal organization of code, or choose a different pattern is?
task - adding new methods in builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a class to implement multiple behaviors, you should have it implement multiple interfaces. It's generally bad practice to code against classes - you sould instead code against interfaces. The difference is subtle, but still quite relevatn and real.

When you find yourself casting explicitly, it usually means that your interfaces are not quite suitable for the task. The goal is to have the client code know as little as possible about the actual type of the objects that it is processing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think to use multiple interfaces. And to create classes, which implement some of them (depending on requirements).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using the interface is that you don't care what the implementation type is and you don't need to specific methods on the subclass. If you do need to call subclass specific methods, you do need to downcast as you have done above.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want to call `builder.buildNewCommand()` means you already know that it is of type `NewScriptBuilder`. Why not just declare it a `NewScriptBuilder` then?

```
NewScriptBuilder builder = new NewScriptBuilder();
...
builder.buildNewCommand();
```

If this is not possible (maybe you are using an external API?) then you can wrap the `ScriptBuilder` instead of extending it:

```
public class NewScriptBuilder {
  private final ScriptBuilder builder;

  public NewScriptBuilder(ScriptBuilder builder) {
    this.builder = builder;
  }

  public void buildNewCommand(TouchPoint startTouchPoint, TouchPoint endTouchPoint) {
    builder.buildTouchDownCommand(startTouchPoint);
    builder.buildSynchronizationCommand();
    builder.buildTouchDownCommand(endTouchPoint);
  }
}
```

and create a new instance whenever you want to use `buildNewCommand`:

```
ScriptBuilder builder = ...;
NewScriptBuilder newBuilder = new NewScriptBuilder(builder);
newBuilder.buildNewCommand();
```